# Is this proof by counterexample valid?

Tags: alternative-proof

This is the given statement and its proof:

$$\exists m \in Z^+, \forall n \in Z^+, m<n$$

**Proof:** This result is false because, for each positive integer m, if we put $n=m$ then n is a positive integer and $m \nless n$.

If I say:

*"This statement is false and a counterexample is $n=1$ since $m \nless 1$ for all positive integers m."*

would it be a valid alternative proof?

Comment: Yes, it works; negating $∃m∀n(m<n)$ we get : $∀m∃n(m \ge n)$ and you have shown that choosing $1$ as value for $n$ we have that : $m \ge 1$, for all $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can disprove any statement by showing that the statement has a counterexample.